# specify ip address for docker for mac

Tags: macos, networking, docker, docker-network

I'm using **Docker for Mac Beta** and it runs from spotlight.

Is there any way to run it from console or force to use any configuration file to specify ip address for docker host.

Right now it changing from 192.168.64.3 to 192.168.64.5 (each start of docker it can have any random IP)

probably I need to configure bridge interface?

```
com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade: true
com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4: 0.0.0.0
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: In **Docker for Mac Beta**  for mac now binds to 127.0.0.1 or host docker.local doesn't not more necesary connect with server ip

Comment: Using the IP is the hack we have to deal with Docker Toolbox. Now it's `docker.local`, enjoy!

Comment: @ShanShan can I use --fixed-cidr somehow?

Comment: Any update on this? 127.0.0.1 doesn't work for me as I'm trying to connect from one container to another via what used to be the "docker machine," but now is Docker for Mac. 127.0.0.1 from inside the container just points to itself.

Answer (score 5):

You can connect to the Docker alpine host via unix socket but I have not been able to figure out how to bridge to the network.

[The docs say:](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/)

> Unfortunately, due to limtations in OSX, we’re unable to route traffic
>   to containers, and from containers back to the host.
>
> Because of the way networking is implemented in Docker for Mac, you
>   cannot see a docker0 interface in OSX. This interface is actually
>   within HyperKit.