# How can I access a docker container via ip address

Tags: networking, docker

I'm trying to replace our vagrant development setup with docker. I'd like to be able to use an ip like 10.10.10.10 for my docker container and allow developers to access their container via that IP. I'm currently using docker on Mac OS, but some developers use Windows.

How can I make this work?

Comment: The question became confusing when you said your container will have ip 10.10.10.10 and their container will have the same IP?  Where are you wanting these development setups to reside?

Comment: Correct, the developer setups are local to their own machine. Our vagrant setup uses config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.10" which creates a private network between the host and the VM. I'm looking to have something similar to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [specify ip address for docker for mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895461/specify-ip-address-for-docker-for-mac). Although that one is about the Beta, doesn't look like the situation has changed.

Comment: This link should help.  http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101-host-mode/

Comment: Also, http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/docker-networking.html
Strongly suggest you go through some docker tutorials first.  Docker is not another kind of VM.  It works differently in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I'm reading the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/) for Docker for Mac correctly, that's not possible

> Per-container IP addressing is not possible
>
> The docker (Linux) bridge network is not reachable from the macOS host.

and

> **I want to connect to a container from the Mac**
>
> Port forwarding works for localhost; --publish, -p, or -P all work. Ports exposed from Linux are forwarded to the Mac.
>
> Our current recommendation is to publish a port, or to connect from another container. Note that this is what you have to do even on Linux if the container is on an overlay network, not a bridge network, as these are not routed.

There is also a pretty interesting discussion [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22753) about why there is no `docker0` bridge to access containers directly. [This comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22753#issuecomment-246054946) suggests a workaround that might be good enough for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should look at making my web app work via localhost:<random port> rather than trying to make it work like our VM

Comment: @Noodles Publishing ports to different IPs looks like a promising option.

Answer (score -1):

docker inspect

foundip address

Then u can connect it by ip address

Comment: This IP address does not work on Docker Desktop on either MacOS or Windows systems, nor does it work on the `docker-machine` setups in common use when this question was first asked.